# Using makefile arguments without foo=

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile I use to compile a single file. When I need to pass an argument, I use target=targetFile.

The script takes the argument, looks for the file (within the same directory) that has the same value as the argument and compiles it.

I use this for compiling problems from uhunt and uva, which use a single c++ file. So I dont' need multiple makefiles for multiple source files. Single makefile for multiple source files is the reason I made the makefile.

Here's the code I have so far

```
OBJS = $(target).o
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11
INCLUDE = -I./$(target)

#default command to run
all : Main-$(target) clean run

#compile and build
Main-$(target) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

#remove object and any other garbage files.
clean:
    rm -rf -d $(target).o *~ *% *# .#*

#remove the compiled file
clean-all:
    $(clean) rm Main-$(target)

#run the compiled file
run:
    ./Main-$(target)
```

The command I use to compile is, 
`make target=sourceFile`

Also I don't include the file extension, I have all my source file extensions to be cpp

What I want in the end is:
`make sourceFile`

Just a side note, for using the command clean and clean-all, I use

`make target=sourceFile clean`

`make target=sourceFile clean-all`

I'd prefer if I can use:

`make sourceFile clean`

`make sourceFile clean-all`

Comment: Maybe move the common parts into a template you can include, and have a narrow main makefile that provides just the specific targets you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use common Makefile variable `MAKECMDGOALS` that contains all targets passed to make.

Please try this variant

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
MAKECMDGOALS := $(filter-out clean, $(MAKECMDGOALS))

.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
$(MAKECMDGOALS):
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c -o Main-$@

clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

Here the lines

```
$(MAKECMDGOALS):
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c -o Main-$@
```

will generate separate build targets for each word in `MAKECMDGOALS`.

Note, we need this Makefile to know that 'clean' is a target for removing stuff, but not to attempt build `Main-clean`. This why we remove `clean` from `MAKECMDGOALS` using filter-out function.

So if we run `make a b clean`, the build system will generate automatically targets for building `Main-a` and `Main-b` and then use already written `clean` target

Comment: I modified the code just a little. The original code was making a folder of the file that was being compiled. Here's the modified code [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Clumsy-Coder/4de8cae3e845728c2d169aaa3e1e429d)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer -- this is a non-standard use of Make, and will therefore open up all kinds of corner cases, so I don't recommend it.  This is better suited for a shell script calling make.  That being said... it is an interesting question.

You can't do `make xxx clean`, and not have it try to build `xxx` (unless you do some really nasty cludge using recursive make, but I won't go there).   You could do something like `make clean-xxx` though, as follows:

```
%:Main-%

Main-%:%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o Main-$@

clean-%:
    rm Main-$*
```

Notice that `%-clean` has a shorter stem, and therefor takes precedence over the `%` if the make target starts with `clean-`.