# How to only pass an argument value to a Makefile target?

Tags: go, makefile

I come from the NodeJS world so I consider the Makefile as the "scripts" part in an npm `package.json`, which may be wrong (or not ?) to do so.

So my idea is to automate repetitive actions when installing a new dependency by typing:

```
make install github.com/stretchr/testify
```

And find a way to get the `github.com/stretchr/testify` parameter **without** having to use the heavy parameter name-value declaration `FOO=bar` (=> `make install DEP=github.com/stretchr/testify`) generally suggested.

So, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40294025/2736233), I tried this:

```
install %:
    go get $*
    godep save ./...
    git add Godeps vendor
    git commit -m "godep: add $*"
```

but unsuccessfully: it runs `go get` without any param and `git commit -m "godep: add"`.

**Trials**

**1 -** When I do that:

```
install %:
    echo $*
```

I see my "github.com/stretchr/testify".

**2 -** When I do that:

```
install %:
    go get ${*}
```

it loops twice and first run `go get` without any param, then runs `go get github.com/stretchr/testify` (as wished).

It looks like `${*}` represents an "array" of params parsing characters groups after the target, the first one being the space between `install` and `github.com/stretchr/testify` and the second one being `github.com/stretchr/testify`.

Comment: This is not possible. Parameters that are not variable definitions are interpreted as Makefile targets. Might I suggest using a shell script instead, then you can say `./install github.com/...`

Comment: Indeed I had the feeling it couldn't be done. I will do that instead. Thank you!

Comment: Just a subquestion @JanKrüger: it should be possible though to declare the shell script in the Makefile and parse the original arguments, which would make that somehow possible, is it ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, common implementations of `make` don't allow you to access the original arguments in any way. `make` simply isn't designed for that kind of thing.

Comment: "Tried unsuccessfully" is not a problem description.  What command did you type?  What output did you get?  If it's not obvious, what about that output is not what you want?

Comment: @MadScientist I gave more details about my two trials.

Comment: You must have an older version of GNU make.  That syntax was made illegal for a while, then it was added back recently but with a warning due to some historical issues with Linux kernel makefiles.  You're not correct about "arrays".  What's happening is that the rule is being run multiple times, once for each goal that you specify on the command line.  Each time its run, the automatic variable `$*` is set appropriately.  It's helpful to read the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use explicit targets and patterns in the same rule, so your rule `% install:` will not work.

You can do this with GNU make using [the `CMDGOALS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.htm), but it's very hackish and error-prone and I don't recommend it.

```
ARG := $(filter-out install,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

install:
        go get $(ARG)
        godep save ./...
        git add Godeps vendor
        git commit -m "godep: add $(ARG)"
```

As you can see you'll need to add handling for situations where there are no other arguments, or where there are more than one other argument, and of course you can't add any more targets without putting them in the `filter-out` list, etc.

Just... not a good way to do it IMO.

Why don't you do something like this instead:

```
install-%:
        go get $*
        godep save ./...
        git add Godeps vendor
        git commit -m "godep: add $*"
```

Then run:

```
make install-github.com/stretchr/testify
```

Comment: Unless I'm wrong I start to think that the target is in fact a sort of regex parsing everything after `make`, is it ? I just need to try something else before accepting your answer.

Comment: That is a pattern rule: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html which is a type of implicit rule: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html  They have nothing to do with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Make variables can probably do what you want:

```
host> cat Makefile
install:
    go get $(P)
    godep save ./...
    git add Godeps vendor
    git commit -m "godep: add $(P)"

host> make install P=github.com/stretchr/testify
```

But using make just for this is probably overkill. It is much more than a scripting language.

Comment: I am well aware of the argument name-value argument in a Makefile as I told in the description ;) The idea was to avoid the arg name part as some other "tasks automators" are able to do.